# Using attrs is it ok to set init=False to an attribute with no default value

Tags: python, python-attrs

I use `attrs` library.

I use some attributes that are set by the `__attrs_post_init__` method.

For them, I want to prevent them from being part of the constructor.

Is it ok to not put a default value, or is it an implicit requirement of putting `init=False`?

The doc is not really clear about it.

```py
import attrs

@attrs.define
class MyClass:
    val1: str = attrs.field(init=False)
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.val1="something"

a = MyClass()
print(a)

a.val1
```

This code is working, however I wonder if it’s relevant regarding the best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine. With `init=False` you're opting out of attrs's `__init__`.

You can always try `import inspect; inspect.getsource(MyClass.__init__)` if you're curious what's happening under the hood.